# MongoDB could not start: bind_ip error: bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket

Tags: linux, mongodb, sockets, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I follow installation instructions for `mongodb-org` in MongoDB documentation. My Ubuntu version is 14.04. This is my `/etc/mongod.conf`

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,54.169.117.134


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

When I try `sudo service mongod start`, it returns `mongod start/running, process 6400` but `sudo service mongod status` always returns `mongod stop/waiting`, so I check `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` and get this:

```
2016-11-04T14:59:21.366+0700 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:99 Cannot assign requested address for socket: 54.169.117.134:27017
2016-11-04T14:59:21.366+0700 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2016-11-04T14:59:21.366+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

I even run this command line to check whether another process is running on port 27017 `sudo netstat -peant | grep ":27017"`, but nothing is running that port, meaning port 27017 is available. Please help me fix this

Comment: I've got the same problem

You find a solution?

Comment: @user3770797 I changed `bindIp` into `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the public IP `54.169.117.134` use the private IP.

Of course, this makes your database public so make sure it is protected with authorization and/or a firewall if you don't want public access.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me using Google Cloud where I was using the public IP instead of the private IP